# Retrieve video title and associate id using Youtube API

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, domdocument

I've been trying to retrieve a list of related video title and associated IDs. The api url is: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/FYpunY-gXxU/related?v=2

My code has been parsing the etag, though it'd be easier to get the "link->alternate" value instead. This value can be found at the XPath: /feed/entry[1]/link[1]@rel. I've been using DOMDocument to attempt this, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code. You'll retrieve your views and your title. To retrieve more data, take a look at https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/FYpunY-gXxU?v=2&alt=json and try figuring out yourself (best practice ;) )

```
    $JSON = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/FYpunY-gXxU?v=2&alt=json");
    $JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
    $views = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'}; //Title
    $title = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'title'}->{'$t'};
    $title = str_replace('"','&#34;',$titel);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I needed to get the name and link or id for the RELATED videos. The JSON version can be found at https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/FYpunY-gXxU/related?v=2&alt=json

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$JSON = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/FYpunY-gXxU/related?v=2&alt=json");
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
$title = $JSON_Data->{'feed'}->{'entry'};
for ($i = 1; $i < 25; $i++)
{
    echo ($title[$i]->{'title'}->{'$t'}) . "<br />";
    echo $title[$i]->{'link'}[0]->{'href'} . "<br /><br />";
}
?>
```